# Parsing error in creating scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

I am creating a scratch org in Cli and getting the error below (see image) in this challenge
[enter link description here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-unlocked-packages/create-test-and-deploy-your-unlocked-package)https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-unlocked-packages/create-test-and-deploy-your-unlocked-package

[image]

Steps already taken!

-Created Project in VSCode
-Authorized an Org

any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: What is in your `project-scratch-def.json`? Is it indeed valid JSON?

Comment: @DavidReed sorry david how do i establish that?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include the relevant code. There are numerous JSON validators available online, and Visual Studio Code will usually provide you with highlighting to show whether or not it is valid.